# Network Traffic increase with Small Result Set

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am currently executing a stored procedure that is using up a ton of network traffic when it executes.  The stored proc executes multiple stored procs within itself as well as functions and subqueries. There are 5 result sets returned each with 1 to 5 records, 10 columns max with VARCHAR(255).

**My question is:**

Does executing multiple Stored Procedures within another Stored Proc cause data to be returned to the client that you can't see, therefor creating network traffic? I thought everything was processed at server and then sent over network after its been processed.

Unfortunately we do not have the ability to use SQL Profile or to query System Tables since this DB is hosted by our provider.

Comment: Every `SELECT` statement in SP returns a result set. If you need only one result set, you need to wrap `SELECT`s into insert into temp table or variable, or remove completely, e.g. comment out.

Comment: Need more details. For instance, what do the SPs and table functions do? How did you determine the SPs are generating a lot of network traffic? Are you sysadmin on the server? If so, you can initiate a trace regardless of who is hosting the server.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Unfortunatley I am not the sysadmin so I can't run a trace.  Another company hosts the SQL server and when I run the SP they contact us and say we are over utilizing our network.  We've identified this happens only when I run the SP.

In this SP, the child SP's are placing values in persistent tables and temp tables before being aggregated at the end.  The temp tables generally have around 2000+ records but the return data to the client is around 5 lines after being grouped. 

I wish I could post all the code but its a proprietary Medical System.